# Formatting Date for Postgres Timestamp with Timezone

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I create a date that matches the format of Postgres' Timestamp with Timezone column type in PHP?

I can't seem to get a date format that works with it.

Comment: Can you please give some code you used?

Comment: I simply asked what I could use in PHP to format the date the same as a column type in Postgres it is a very specific question. I've read the documentation however there's nothing there to have a 2 digit offset. The offsets are 4 digits.

Comment: all of date()'s output values are strings. you can use string functions to modify the output, e.g. it only gives you 4 digit offsets? use substr to lop off the unwanted digits... And I'm not being a dick about, just tied of lazy idiots thinking everyone here is going to do their job for them. Either show what you attempted, to show that you DID try to do this, or go elsewhere.